# Ruby on Rails Formtastic Checkbox Not Checking (Collection.map)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, collections, formtastic

I am working on a rails (& gems) project migration, and i am having some problems due to formtastic checkboxs which aren't being checked ( :collection => ... .map { ... } ).

The scenario happens when editing an object, it is supposed to print all possible profiles, translating them to the current user locale, and check which are associated with my current user.

The following code is working for **Formtastic 1.2.4** and there was no model/controller/view code or database modified. Supposedly it would work for 2.2.1, but it happens that doesn't work for any 2.x version. ***Rails v.3.1.12***

**Views/_form.html.haml**

```
= f.input :groups, :as => :check_boxes, :hint => i18n_hint_str("user_roles"), :collection  => @current_organization.groups.joins(:permissions).permission_on("idea","index").map{ |u| [i18n_user_str("role.#{u.name}"),u.id] }
```

> The select boxs below are just an output test, which surprisingly works in both versions, but what i truly want are the **checkboxs**.

**Formtastic 1.2.4**

> Image Link : ***i.stack.imgur.com/7aruc.png***

**Formtastic 2.2.1**

> Image Link : ***i.stack.imgur.com/Af7LK.png***

If i remove the .map part

```
= f.input :groups, :as => :check_boxes, :hint => i18n_hint_str("user_roles"), :collection  => @current_organization.groups.joins(:permissions).permission_on("idea","index")
```

It will check the associated profiles, but without the translation part (**Formtastic 2.2.1**)

> Image Link : ***i.stack.imgur.com/M0Xd7.png***

Any ideas to make this working on Formtastic 2.2.1? I don't want to use javascript in this.

Thanks.

Comment: Same issue here. If I remove the `collection`, then the boxes are *checked*, but instead of their names that I would use a collection for it users there Object model and Memory reference number.